# USA map drill-down in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, geography

I'm looking for some component (preferably freeware) what will provide me the ability to take an image of the USA and have a user click a state. The image of the state will then display, giving the ability to click either a region, or a county, and drill down further.  A user would then be able to select one or more counties.  I'm also trying to stay away from any google mapping features.

I don't mind having to create this feature from scratch, but I'm having trouble finding tutorials or similar articles on such a technique to get me started on the right path.

Any suggestions would be helpful! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have see maps on 2 components

Dundas
http://www.dundas.com/Components/Products/Map/NET/

And FusionCharts.
http://www.fusioncharts.com/maps/Demos.asp

Here is a Drill Down demo 
http://www.fusioncharts.com/maps/Demos/AJAX/Index.html

I do not know if its what you looking, but its a start.

Comment: Yes, that is a similar to what I'm looking for. Any similar open source/freeware stuff out there?